# How do I find all variables with a certain scoped option?

Tags: .net, powershell

all!

I apologise in advance if this has been asked or discussed before; I was not able to find anything from Google.

Here is how I was able to find all variables in a PowerShell script that have a certain scoped option (example here: `ReadOnly`):

```
 gv | %{if ( ($_.options -band ([System.Management.Automation.ScopedItemOptions]::ReadOnly).value__)) {echo $_.name}}
```

There is also the `None` ScopedItemOption which equals 0. Finding these variables is easy:

```
 gv | %{if ( $_.options -eq 0) {echo $_.name}}
```

Does anyone have a better suggestion for doing this?

Thanks!

Carlos Nunez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cosmetic version. You can also use the Scope parameter to get variables from other scopes, like Global,Local or Script:

```
Get-Variable | Where-Object {$_.Options -match 'readonly'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: Perfect, as usual! Thanks, Shay. :)